# Normalise ASCII numbers to digit numbers

Tags: rust, ascii

[Running example on play.rust-lang.org](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=%23!%5Bfeature(asm%2C%20simd%2C%20thread_local%2C%20unsafe_destructor)%5D%0A%23!%5Bfeature(core%2C%20libc%2C%20collections%2C%20std_misc%2C%20io%2C%20path)%5D%0A%23!%5Ballow(dead_code%2C%20unused_variables)%5D%0A%23!%5Ballow(unused_features)%5D%0A%0Aextern%20crate%20libc%3B%0A%0Astatic%20VERSION%3A%20%26%27static%20str%20%3D%20%22rustc%201.0.0-nightly%20(4db0b3246%202015-02-25)%20(built%202015-02-26)%22%3B%0A%0Afn%20show%3CT%3A%20std%3A%3Afmt%3A%3ADebug%3E(e%3A%20T)%20%7B%20println!(%22%7B%3A%3F%7D%22%2C%20e)%20%7D%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20show(%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20number%20%3D%20b%22122222%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20for%20sequence%20in%20number.windows(6)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20product%20%3D%20sequence.iter().fold(1%2C%20%7Ca%2C%20%26b%7C%20a%20*%20(b%20as%20u64))%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20println!(%22product%20of%20%7B%3A%3F%7D%20is%20%7B%7D%22%2C%20sequence%2C%20product)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%7D)

```
fn main() {
    show({
        let number = b"123456";
        for sequence in number.windows(6) {
            let product = sequence.iter().fold(1, |a, &b| a * (b as u64));
            println!("product of {:?} is {}", sequence, product);
        }
    });
}
```

Instead of having an output like "product of [49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54] is 15312500000" I need the normal numbers in the brackets and the normalized result for the product.
Trying around with `- b'0'` to subtract the 48 to get the normal digits in line 5 doesn't work, i.e.

```
a * ((b as u64) -b'0')
```

or

```
(a - b'0') * (b as u64)
```

Seems I'm missing something here, for example I have no idea what exactly are the 'a' and 'b' values in the fold(). Can anyone enlighten me? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at [the signature of `fold`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/core/iter/trait.IteratorExt.html#method.fold), we can see that it takes two arguments:

```
fn fold<B, F>(self, init: B, f: F) -> B
   where F: FnMut(B, Self::Item) -> B
```

`init`, which is of some arbitrary type `B`, and `f`, which is a closure that takes a `B` value and an element from the iterator, in order to compute a new `B` value. The whole function returns a `B`. The types are strongly suggestive of what happens: the closure `f` is repeatedly called on successive elements of the iterator, passing the computed `B` value into the next `f` call. Checking [the implementation](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/e233987ce1de88a48db2ce612019ba644d3cf5dd/src/libcore/iter.rs#L607-L626) confirms this suspicion:

```
let mut accum = init;
for x in self {
    accum = f(accum, x);
}
accum
```

It runs through the iterator, passing the accumulated state into the closure in order to compute the next state.

First things first, lets put the type on the `fold` call:

```
let product = sequence.iter().fold(1, |a: u64, &b: &u8| a * (b as u64));
```

That is, the `B` type we want is `u64` (that's what our final product will be), and the item type of the iterator is `&u8`, a reference to a byte.

Now, we can manually inline the definition of `fold` to compute `product` to try to clarify the desired behaviour (I'm ignoring the normalisation for now):

```
let mut accum = 1;
for x in sequence.iter() {
    accum = { // the closure
        let a: u64 = accum;
        let &b: &u8 = x;
        a * b as u64
    }
}
let product = accum;
```

Simplifying:

```
let mut product = 1;
for &b in sequence.iter() {
    product = product * (b as u64)
}
```

Hopefully this makes it clearer what needs to happen: `b` runs across each byte, and so it is the value that needs adjustment, to bring the ASCII encoded value down to the expected 0..10 range.

So, you were right with:

```
a * ((b as u64) -b'0')
```

However, the details mean that fails to compile, with a type error: `b'0'` has type `u8`, but `b as u64` as type `u64`, and it's not legal to use `-` with `u64` and `u8`. Moving the normalisation to happen before the `u64` cast will ensure this works ok, since then you're subtracting `b` (which is a `u8`) and a `u8`:

```
product * (b - b'0') as u64
```

All in all, the `fold` might look clearer (and actually work) as:

```
let product = sequence.iter()
    .fold(1, |prod, &byte| prod * (byte - b'0') as u64);
```

(I apologise for giving you such confusing code on IRC.)

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed answer: I barely understand 90% of the context  but my Rust knowledge is extremly small so I will reread it tomorrow when I sleeped enough.
I tried your new fold(), but it didn't change anything? Result should be 5832 from 9*9*8*9: http://is.gd/UZ5asw

Comment: Ah: including the number in that way is also including the newline characters `\n` and the spaces. Suffixing each line in `\` will ensure that the newline and the leading spaces don't appear in the actual runtime string: http://is.gd/eiq292

Comment: My IDE did that formatting due to the 80 line limit, didn't know it would include the spaces + newline to while splitting the number. Learned a lot about Rust today, big thanks :).
By the way, what would be your way for including the number without having to deal with the spaces & \n? My first thought was via

    "static"

but I didn't know the variable type for a bytestring and so I did it in the main function, letting the compiler doing the type stuff.

Comment: You could put the number into an external file (e.g. `number.txt`) and load it with the `include_bytes!("number.txt")` macro, which will load the number at compile time into a `&[u8]` array (you may have to be careful about a trailing `\n` in the file). A byte string has type `&'static [u8]`.

Comment: Neat, a simple "let readnumbers = include_bytes!("task08 numbers.txt");" works :). Doesn't seem to include a \n, test with windows(4) shows the anticipated result.

Comment: (Sorry to bug you, but don't forget to upvote/accept if the answer is correct. :) )

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to `fold`, you can use [`map`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.IteratorExt.html#tymethod.map) and [`MultiplicativeIterator::product`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.MultiplicativeIterator.html#tymethod.product). I find that the two steps help make it clearer what is happening.

```
#![feature(core)]

use std::iter::MultiplicativeIterator;

fn main() {
    let number = b"123456";
    for sequence in number.windows(6) {
        let product = sequence.iter().map(|v| (v - b'0') as u64).product();
        println!("product of {:?} is {}", sequence, product);
    }
}
```

You could even choose to split up the resizing from `u8` to `u64`:

```
sequence.iter().map(|v| v - b'0').map(|v| v as u64).product();
```

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, an alternative is [`product`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.product) + [`to_digit`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.char.html#method.to_digit): ([`itertools`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.9.0/itertools) was used to print the contents of the iterator)

```
use {itertools::Itertools, std::char};

fn main() {
    let number = b"123456";

    let sequence = number
        .iter()
        .map(|&c| u64::from(char::from(c).to_digit(10).expect("not a digit")));
    let product: u64 = sequence.clone().product();
    println!("product of {:?} is {}", sequence.format(", "), product);
}
```

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6034ef3c4c748805ac22c37117920974))